# change the width of an accordion element when user rezise the website in jQuery

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-ui-accordion

I would like to change the width from % to the width of element accordion - 244px (the total size of elements in the right of the accordion).

```
 $(function() {
        $('.accordion > li').hoverIntent(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);

              >>>  $this.stop().animate({'width':'80%'},500);   <<<

                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'5em'},1000);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                }
        );
    });
```

I was thinking:

```
var accordwidth = $("accordion").width() -244;
$this.stop().animate({'width':accordwidth },500);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.accordion > li').hoverIntent(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var wide1 = $('body').width();
                    var wide2 = $('li.bg1').width()*3;
                    var wide3 = wide1 - wide2 - 4;
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':wide3},500);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).hide();
                      $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'5em'},500);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I am sure it could be a better syntax but it work.
wide1 is the parent of the accordion, wide2 is the space taken by three elements of accordion(4 elements), wide3 is the space available after I deduct from the body the space taken by 3 another elements + the border taken by the border of these elements.
I put this solution for people like me that don't know javascript & spent hour to find a way to resolve this specific problem.